# create an import function buttonn in kivy

Tags: python, file, kivy

I want to create an 'import' Button that chooses a file from Desktop:

I tried this but it's not working :

The .py file

```
def load(self):
    import os
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    sys.path.append(path)
```

The .kv file :

```
Button:
     text: "Load"
     on_release: root.load()
```

Comment: Be specific. What does "not working" mean? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Check out this documentation: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html

Comment: I don't get any errors , my main objective is to make the button navgate through the files using kivy .

Comment: As said D.Manasreh before, you should read https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html

Comment: I did , but I haven't find anything , just to clarify , i want the filechooser to be customised in one button .